# Change string value by address C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to change the value of a string by passing its address to a function.
I get NULL as a result.I tried strcpy but it dosen't work for pointers on strings.

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeStr (char ** tmpP){
    char* test="Hello world !";
    char** add=&test;
    tmpP=add;


    }

int main()   {

    char* tmp;
    changeStr(&tmp);
    printf("\n %s \n",tmp);


     return 0;


     }
```

result :

> (NULL)

Comment: @George because he wants the `tmp` variable to be changed after the call to `changeStr`.

Comment: @George because it dosen't works, i get NULL and i understand why.

Comment: @W.draoui read Bathsheba's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the behaviour of your code is *undefined* as `changeStr` is a no-op, and you are attempting to call `printf` with the *uninitialised* variable `tmp`. That accounts for your (arbitrary) output. On other occasions the compiler might eat your cat.

`add` has automatic storage duration, and `tmpP` is the result of a value copy of `&tmp` from the caller. These assignments, although perfectly valid, are not visible to the calling function `main()`.

The solution is to write

```
*tmpP = "Hello World";
```

as the *only* statement in `changeStr`.

You should note that `tmp` in `main()` will point to a *read-only* string literal.

Comment: it works, thank you. I have another question in the same context.
void changeStr (char ** tmpP){
 char* test="Hello world !";
 *tmpP=test;
   if(test)
   free(test);

 
 }
why free dosen't work ?

Comment: You can only `free` a pointer returned back from `malloc` and friends.

Comment: thanks, but also this code dosen't work (Aborted) :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeStr (char ** tmpP){
 char* test=malloc(strlen("Hello world !")+1);
  test="Hello world !";
  printf("test=%s \n",test);
       * tmpP=test;
  if(test)
   free(test);

 
 }

int main()   {
 
 char* tmp;
 changeStr(&tmp);
 printf("\n %s \n",tmp);
 
 
  return 0;
  
  
  }

Comment: You probably ought to ask another question: it will be clearer that way.

Comment: Ok but i will need to wait at least 1 hour, thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

What your doing is the mistake, `tmpP=add;` you thought that the `add` value will point to `tmpP`.

If you want to change the value of string passed to function, you can do in this way. I saw already **@Bathseba** pointed out.

**Try this,**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeStr (char ** tmpP){
    char* test;
    char** add=&test;
    *tmpP= "Hello world !";
}

int main()   {
    /* Here it has string cruel that pass to function*/
    char* tmp="Cruel";
    changeStr(&tmp);
    printf("\n %s \n",tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world !
```

What you did.

```
void changeStr (char ** tmpP){
    char* test = "Hello world !";
    char** add=&test;
    tmpP=add; //<-- Here your assigning add to tmpP, it shouldn't.
}
```